# Is it possible to select only the faces that form the first "level"?

Tags: mesh, faces

I would like to do a mesh cleanup on this object - the blend file is attached down below now.

How can I make sure that there are no other faces under the floor? Exactly meant are the faces under the floor (see attached picture 1) that form squares or the faces that are in the building as in the case of picture 2?

Is it possible to select only the faces that form the first "level" - also those of the tree and building etc.? In other words, the faces that are essential for the highest level of detail in an UV map, without leaving any faces that would only make the UV map unnecessarily large.

I hope one understands what I mean. Otherwise please just ask for more information :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Still a little confusing.  Bisect with XY plane at z=0 and ditch all geo below?

Comment: Would be possible if the faces were not on different levels, I think.

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far? (You can try sharing the .blend without textures, it should be small enough.)

Comment: The file is now available for download.

Comment: @Jachym Michal I haven't really tried much myself. I'm relatively new at blender and was quickly overwhelmed.

Comment: Hello :). The mesh is really messy, so any edits will be really cumbersome. You can remesh it automatically first, but that'll reset the UV map. If you don't *have to*, I'd keep it as it is :).

Comment: A reset of the UV map would be fine. Remesh via the Object Data Properties Menu? If so which settings would work here? Recent attempts by me have always caused my PC to crash (my settings: Voxel - Size 0.1 - Adap. 0 - Fix poles - Volume).

Comment: I'm no expert on remeshing :). But the *Remesh modifier* seems to give best results in this case https://imgur.com/a/3tysV46. Just don't forget to backup the mesh first, once the modifier is applied, there's no going back :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select few unwanted faces (one in each X, Y direction)
- Search for *Select Similar > Normal*
- *Separate* <kbd>P</kbd> *by Selection* and hide newly generated object
- For faces oriented Z use type *Co-Plannar* because type *Normal* takes into acount too many top faces

Tips:

- you can delete them directly, but it is better to check if in this separation isnt a face you want to join back
- use *Face Orientation* overlay to see better unwanted faces

[image]

[image]

[image]

This technique is not a perfect, but does some job.

[image]

I don't know what is the purpose of this model, but if you don't care about UV Map and some loose of "accuracy", some cleaning can be done also witm *Merge by Distance* like 0.2 (in Vertices select mode) and search for *Fill Holes* operator to close some gaps. In this case you don't have to boder with separation of unwanted faces. They will be removed anyway.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's it! Many thanks :) Could you perhaps still explain the first point? I can't get anywhere near the result that you have there.  Yours is close to perfect.

Comment: It is not a one step process, but can be done in 2 minutes. For vertical or angled faces Normal select is fine (https://imgur.com/jm1bj1u), for a faces orientated to Z axis is better Co-Plannar (because Normal type selects many other top faces).

Comment: You are a hero! ;-) One last thing, then I am completely happy! Is there an automatic method besides closing the gaps manually?

Comment: I will have to tell my kids :) Answer extended, but in this kind of messy thing, its hard to recommend something :) Good luck